# How do I extract inner text from HTML markup?

Tags: haskell, haskell-tagsoup

I have the following code:

```
import Text.HTML.TagSoup

parseTags "<hello>my&amp;</world>"
```

which is giving me output like: `[TagOpen "hello" [],TagText "my&",TagClose "world"]`. But I want to get only `[TagText "my&"]`. And I can do this:

```
filter (~== "my&")$ parseTags "<hello>my&amp;</world>"
```

which will give me output like: `[TagText "my&"]`. But I do not know what is inside the `TagText`, i.e. `"my&"`. My ultimate target is to get `"my&"` which I can get by

```
map(fromTagText) $ filter (~== "my&")$ parseTags "<hello>my&amp;</world>"
```

I tried to use `TagText`, but can’t do it right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> filter isTagText (parseTags "<hello>my&amp;</world>")
[TagText "my&"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really only want the `"my&"` you can use `innerText` from TagSoup:

```
innerText (parseTags "<hello>my&amp;</world>")
```

It only looks for text tags and concatenates them. So this

```
innerText (parseTags "<hello>my&amp;</world><foo>bar</foo>")
```

gets you `"my&bar"`.